# Meteor renders parent multiple times for each object in collection provided by template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

My HTML code is:

```
{{#each slides}}
   {{> slide}}
{{/each}}
```

and my javascript helper is:

```
Template.draggables.slides = function() {
return LiveSlides.find();
};
```

I've tried `{{#isolate}}` around the `{{#each}}` statement, as well as a sub-template, as well as a combination of the two, and many many more permutations. All the parent templates are being re-rendered, and for each object in the collection. So on first load of the web page, if I have 10 objects in the collection, all parent templates will be rendered. I'm logging it all. I'm pretty sure it doesn't operate this way with regular Session variables--I think it's the collections acting funny. Anyone knows what the problem could be?

UPDATE -- I JUST CREATED A NEW BLANK APP TO TEST AND I'M STILL GETTING PARENT TEMPLATES RE-RENDERING THEMSELVES -- HERE'S ALL THE APP HAS:

```
 <body>
  {{> parent}}
</body>

<template name="parent">
    {{>child}}
</template>

<template name="child">
    {{#each desks}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</template>


Template.parent.rendered = function() {
    console.log('parent rendered');
};

Template.child.desks = function() {
    return Desks.find();
};
```

Comment: Could you show your parent template? Does it have reactive variables in it? The normal behavior is 2 renders, the initial, and again when the data is received from the server that fills the collections up.

Comment: i have the collection nested in a separate sub-template and neither have other reactive variables: <template name="graph_paper">
 <div id="mainDesk">  
  <div class="mainDeskInner graphPaper">
   {{>draggables}}
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<template name="draggables">
 {{#each slides}}
  {{>draggable}}
 {{/each}}
</template>

Comment: it's definitely rendering parent templates. I nested 4 templates and added logging to the rendered callbacks, and for every item in the collection, all parent templates up the entire tree are re-rendered: http://snapplr.com/3yst ..the same goes if you use {{#isolate}} everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is the parent "rendered" callback is getting called for each child that is rendered. So the parent isn't actually being put back on the DOM again. Its rendered callback is being fired by the children. If there's a particular use case you're trying to accomplish let me know and I'll try to extend my answer with some suggestions.